# T-SQL Audit Table changes without Triggers, is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Right now we are auditing a Table by using two DateTime fields:

```
[Creation] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getutcdate()),
[Modification] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getutcdate())
```

Then there is a Trigger on UPDATE that change the value of [Modification] as following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Record_Updated]
ON [dbo].[MyTable]
FOR UPDATE /* Fire this trigger when a row UPDATE */
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] 
    SET [dbo].[Table].[Modification] = GETUTCDATE()
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
    JOIN INSERTED ON INSERTED.MyID = [dbo].[MyTable].[MyID]
END
```

The question is, because we are dealing with a Customer DB and they do not want TRIGGERS, is there any other way in T-SQL to achieve the same result?
The DB is >= SQL 2012 or SQL Azure

Comment: I would argue that what you are doing is not auditing. All you are doing is setting a couple of date columns to indicate the last time the row was modified. Also, your comment in the trigger says it will fire for updates and inserts but it will only fire for updates. Regardless, you could add this logic to the procedure that does your inserts and updates. Otherwise there really isn't much you can do other than a trigger.

Comment: I have updated the comment inside my code
Unfortunately there are no SP at all, the tables are handled by a third party application, this is why I have introduced TRIGGERS, because the DAL (Data Application Layer) is not capable of updating these fields when a new ROW in created and an existing one is modified.
So with SQL Server the only 'eventing' is by using TRIGGERS?

Comment: Yes. The event is an insert, update or delete and you handle that event with a trigger.

Comment: Have you considered CDC (Change Data Capture)? It places some restrictions on editions of SQL Server which you can use, but it's far superior to triggers in terms of audit.

Comment: No, I didn't know CDC @RogerWolf, I will have a look at this alternative